# Adding up Excused time off in Attendance Tracker

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am working on an attendance tracker for work. I have most of it figured out except for one thing. Every week for the first year that an employee works for us, they gain a maximum of two hours of Excused  Time Off. One hour is gained if they have perfect attendance for the week in question. The second hour is earned if they come to work on a priority day, (even if they are late). I'm having trouble coming up with a way to check for those two hours. I have a table that lists the work weeks starting on Monday.

What I was thinking of doing for the perfect attendance was to look for any attendance dates in column A that fall in between the week in question's start date and the next week's start date (column K)and then checking if it was listed as unexcused in column E. But I have no idea how to set it up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have rearranged the columns and didn't use all of them, as I was not sure how some related to the question at hand. Columns A,B,C and D are inputs. I changed the "Priority" values from yes/no to True/False. The "Find Week" button activates the following macro to fill in Column E.

```
Sub findweek()

Dim absence As Integer: Dim week As Byte

Range("E2:E100").ClearContents

    absence = 2 'find the first absence in column A

    week = 2    'find the first week in column B

        Do While Cells(absence, 1) <> 0 'loop through the absences in column A

            Do While Cells(week, 4) <> 0    'loop through weeks in column B

'compare the date in column A to the begining of week in column B

            If Cells(absence, 1) > Cells(week, 4) Then
                week = week + 1
            ElseIf Cells(absence, 1) = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                Cells(week - 1, 5) = Cells(absence, 1): absence = absence + 1: week = 2
            End If

            Loop    'count until you run out of "Mondays"

        Exit Do
        Loop    'count until you run out of "dates"

End Sub
```

The values for Column F are filled in by the following:

```
=IF(E2="",1,IF(VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$100,3,FALSE)=TRUE,2,0))
```

Cell G1 sums the values in column F

I hope that this will give you an idea about how to set up the project.

[image: Column letters and Row numbers are not pictured]